# Golang generate a consistent hash for jpeg image without writing to disk

Tags: image, go, jpeg

New to golang imaging

I am attempting to generate a consistent hash for a jpeg image.
Loading the image and generating a hash value on the raw bytes gives me a different hash when I reload the image back in after writing to disk as JPEG (which expected).  As soon as i write the RBGA as JPEG to disk the pixels are modified and this breaks the hash that I previously calculate earlier.

Just hashing the file `hash("abc.jpeg")` would mean I have to write to disk ; read it back in ; gen the hash etc..

- are there any settings I can use when reading / writing that can control the behaviour of the output jpeg pixels
- should I even be using *image.RGBA? the input image is *image.YCbCr?

```
// Open the input image file
inputFile, _ := os.Open("a.jpg")
defer inputFile.Close()

// Decode the input image
inputImage, _, _ := image.Decode(inputFile)

// Get the dimensions of the input image
width := inputImage.Bounds().Dx()
height := inputImage.Bounds().Dy()
subWidth := width / 4
subHeight := height / 4

// Create a new image
subImg := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, subWidth, subHeight))
draw.Draw(subImg, subImg.Bounds(), inputImage, image.Point{0, 0}, draw.Src)

// id want the hashes to be the same for read / write but they will always differ
hash1 := sha256.Sum256(imageToBytes(subImg))
fmt.Printf("<---OUT [%s] %x\n", filename, hash1)
jpg, _ := os.Create("mytest.jpg")
_ = jpeg.Encode(jpg, subImg, nil)
jpg.Close()

// upon reading it back in the pixels are ever so slightly diff
f, _ := os.Open("mytest.jpg")
img, _, _ := image.Decode(f)
jpg_input := image.NewRGBA(img.Bounds())
draw.Draw(jpg_input, img.Bounds(), img, image.Point{0, 0}, draw.Src)
hash2 := sha256.Sum256(imageToBytes(jpg_input))
fmt.Printf("--->IN  [%s] %x\n", filename, hash2)

            // real world use case is..
            // generate subtile of large image plus hash
            // if hash in a dbase
            //    pixel walk to see if hash collision occurred
            //    if pixels are different
            //       deal with it...
            ///   else
            //      object.filename = dbaseb.filename
            // else
            //     add filename to dbase with hash as the lookup
            //     write to jpeg to disk
```

Comment: You should hash the encoded jpeg. You can hash it while writing to the file using an `io.MultiWriter`

Comment: Can you give more of an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the hash as a target for a writer, and use the `io.MultiWriter` to compute hash while writing to the file:

```
hash:=sha256.New()
jpeg.Encode(io.MultiWriter(file,hash),img,nil)
hashValue:=hash.Sum(nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have it working with

```
output := new(bytes.Buffer)
_ = jpeg.Encode(output, subImg, nil)
hash := sha256.Sum256(output.Bytes())
// write it later when i want with...
jpg.Write(output.Bytes())
```

Comment: Burak Serdar's answer is essentially the same thing, just a little more elegant.  `io.MultiWriter` is useful, you should check it out